# Using an API with Zapier but getting "The app returned ""rest_data" param is incorrect. JSON data expected"."

Tags: zapier

So i grab data from an Airtable and then have a custom PUT as the second action using Samba Lives API, specifically Sessions -> PUT Session https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/2014682/samba-live-rest-api/6YzutHM#c87c1db7-2b5c-9b2b-7d63-6b531793cfe2

This is the data in the custom PUT:

```
Method: PUT
URL: https://samba.live/api/2/ourusername/session
Data Pass-Through? No
Data:
input_type=json&rest_data={
"topic": "Crazy Topic",
"duration": 30, 
"start_time": "2025-09-10 12:00:00", 
"invited_participants":[
{
"email":"flast@company.com",
"first_name":"First",
"last_name":"Last",
"role":2,
"send_email_invitation":true
},
{
"email": "first.last@gmail.com",
"first_name": "First",
"last_name": "Last",
"role": 1,
"send_email_invitation": true
}
],
}
Unflatten- yes
Basic Auth- ourusername|ourpassword
Headers- none
```

But the test fails and says "App returned "rest_data" param is incorrect. JSON is expected."

I'm not really sure what to try and Zapier just said we don't help with that. Only thing i could think to try was to delete the input_type section, and that returned with an error saying "Topic is required." Same thing when i left most of it and just deleted the rest_data part.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed - apparently the comma after the ] threw everything off.